# Regarding bitwise shift operator in C

Tags: c, bit, bit-shift

According to text:
"In rare case of C/C++ compiler that does not perform sign extension on right shift of a negative number, the trick to shift right to divide the number fails"

Consider the following example:

```
unsigned int i = 0b10000000; // 128
i = i >> 1; // i equals 01000000 i.e. 64
```

That is the only way I know to block sign extension. Also, by adding unsigned it becomes a positive number so please correct.

Comment: `0b10000000` is not standard C syntax. Are you using a compiler that supports it as an extension?

Comment: If it is not standard C syntax, so how do you work with binary/hexadecimal/octal numbers in C?

Comment: Hexadecimal (`0x80`) or, more rarely, octal (`0200`). Each digit maps directly to 4 (or 3) bits. The `0b` syntax would be convenient, but C doesn't support it. And I really am curious: are you using a compiler that permits `0b10000000`?

Comment: I haven't compiled this code yet with gcc, but yes I know it works with embedded C compilers. so, you might be correct. Let me know, also if an interview you asked a similar question then I will you deal with binary numbers

Comment: I doubt that *all* embedded C compilers support binary literals. gcc does support them as an extension; `gcc -pedantic` warns about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign extension on bitwise right-shift of negative number is implementation-defined in C. It means it is up to the compiler to decide if it performs the sign propagation and the compiler documentation has to document the selected behavior.

From the C Standard:

> (C99, 6.5.7) "If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined."

Among compilers, `gcc` always propagates the sign:

> Signed `>>' acts on negative numbers by sign extension.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html

Comment: So, if an interviewer asks us right shift the bits of a given signed binary negative number, so we should directly flow in 1 from left or should we mention this to interviewer?

Comment: Of course you should first start to say it is implementation-defined and asks for the behavior of the implementation.

Comment: And you should almost never use shift operators on signed integers. If you want to divide a number by 2, just divide by 2 and let the compiler figure out how to do it efficiently. By micro-optimizing your source code, you could even interfere with the compiler's optimizations.